# Tab bar application with navigation Controller and UIBarButtonitem

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uinavigationbar

i created a small tabbed application and added 5 viewControllers to that tabBar. And i added a NavigationController to that tab bar. My problem is i'm not able to add the BarButtons to the navigationBar. I am using StoryBoard.

**Case-1**

in **FirstViewCountroller.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
   UIBarButtonItem *editBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(editAction)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = editBarButtonItem;
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

in this case i'm not getting the bar button but getting the tabBar and navigationBar

**Case-2**

I tried in another way.. modified some of my code

in 
**Appdelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
    FirstViewController *ivc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginView"];
    UINavigationController *navigationController=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:ivc];
    self.window.rootViewController =nil;
    self.window.rootViewController = navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

in this case i'm getting the barbutton and navigationBar but i'm not getting the tabBar.

any one help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

The code you wrote in the AppDelegate.m is incorrect. You have to make the TabBarController the "InitialViewController".
Its better you do it in storyboard and not from code.
Below is the screenshot.

First take a UITabBarController and make it initial view controller:

[image]

Then take a UINavigationController and make it rootViewController for the UITabBarController (Like this):

[image]

and this :

[image]

Do the same thing with a UIViewController for your UINavigationController (like this):

[image]

and this:

[image]

You will get something like this in the storyboard after adding a few more:

[image]

Now you can use any number of controllers according to your requirement.

Now you can add the UIBarButton in your UINavigationBar.

Hope this helps. Thanks cheers.

Comment: thanq for ur answer. Like this i use some many UINavigationcotrollers i want to add. but every NavigationBar having the common left and right bar buttons and its functionality is also same..

Comment: You can manually add barbuttons in storyboard on the navigationbar of the controller and make IBAction in the controller and use the method. You wil not have to do that programatically.